# The font kerning on the Gnome Terminal is broken

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

After upgrading to 16.04, my terminal looks like this:
[image]

The font is the default one. How can I debug/fix this

Comment: That isn't the default Terminal font (Ubuntu Mono)

Comment: Seems like Ubuntu Mono is broken/not installed, try `sudo apt install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family`

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Thanks! After I selected "Custom Font" in the terminal profile preferences and switched to Ubuntu Mono, it looks all right now.

Comment: You can post that as an answer, if you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Terminal font seems to be set to a non-monospace font.

The solution is to set the Terminal font to Ubuntu Mono (default Terminal font — or any monospace font you like).

In the Terminal, go to *Edit* → *Profile Preferences*:

[image: Terminal profile preferences]

Check the *Custom font* checkbox and click on the big button next to the checkbox and choose *Ubuntu Mono regular*:

[image: Select font]

then click *Select*. You should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Use this commmand:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```